# MongoInvalidArgumentError: Update document requires atomic operators during attempted upsert

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

[image]

I'm working with node and mongodb 5. I have a unique index added to the Parcel property of my collection. As I run the program while testing, I get:

```
MongoBulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: mydata.pima2 index: Parcel_1 dup key: { Parcel: "AARON" }
```

My code:

```
for (let j = 0; j < lastNameRecords.length; j++) {
        const ln = lastNameRecords[j].name;
        const recordsObj = { 'Parcel': ln, 'recordNum': 'TBD' };
        recordsArr.push(recordsObj);
    }

    console.log('number of records: ', recordsArr.length);
    try {
-->        const response = await collection.insertMany(recordsArr, { ordered: false });
        const updated = await collection.updateOne(result, { recordNum: 'ERD' });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
```

Th error is occurring at the line with the arrow above. Obviously as I test,  I am inserting multiple records , all of which have been previously inserted into the 'pima2' collection. I want to avoid causing an error or handle it so that I can move on to the next statement

Thinking that maybe the best approach here is an upsert, I have decided to change

```
const response = await collection.insertMany(recordsArr, { ordered: false });
```

I am confused about https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/ .  I'd tried

```
const response = await collection.updateMany({}, recordsArr, { upsert: true });
```

but now getting the error in the title. How do I fix this?

update:

I havnt defined a schema but a screenshot of a record in my pima2 collection is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like within your the `Schema` for your collection you have put the field `Parcel` with the option `unique: true` if so all values should be unique. Most of the times if i get this issue this is the case, if can you add the `Schema` for your collection and let's see if we can figure it out ;-)

Comment: please see update and screenshot at top

Comment: Have you added an index on `Parcel`?

Comment: Looking at your current data I think the `index` (if it is there on `Parcel`) forces each value in the field to be unique, you can of course test this by deleting the one already existing document and then running your code again, if it then works it probably forces unique values.

Comment: Yes - I added a second unique index on Parcel

Comment: Then I think what I said earlier is what is happening, a document with the same value in the field `Parcel` is being added and that throws the Error.

Comment: I think this is the kind of functionality you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23146766/creating-multiple-documents-in-mongoose-only-if-it-does-not-currently-exist

Comment: I'm familiar with unique indexes. My question is how to handle the expected "MongoBulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection" (see above) . I want the code In the try block above to continue without error even though no inserts can be performed because the documents have been previously inserted.

Comment: The article I provided gives you a way to do this right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the mongo create function. So Just to make sure I understand, you are saying that by creating the documents I can bypass the insertion problem?

Comment: Now that I understand the problem it is an interesting one indeed, because in updateMany you cannot pass an array of `Objects` searching for a better solution I came across this: https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/upsert `bulkWrite` seems to do the trick for doing multiple updates so you can use the `.map` over your array and create a bulk write of `updateOne`s and with upsert